# What is this high-order function called?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, functional-programming, naming-conventions

I'm in doubt what to call a high-order function that transforms a function so it uses an array instead of an argument-list. It's complicated to explain in words, so there's an example in JavaScript:

```
sum = function(a,b){ return a+b; };
foo = function(fn){
    return function(arr){
        return fn.apply(fn,arr);
    };
};
different_sum = foo(sum);
log(sum(2,3)); //5
log(different_sum([2,3])); //5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a similar method for Scala functions that takes an n-ary function and returns a unary function that takes an n-tuple as the only argument. They call the method `tupled`, and you can see it in the [documentation for `Function5`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function5.html) (or any of the other function arities greater than 1).

Answer (score 1):

In the classic *Javascript: The Good Parts* this is referenced as the *apply invocation pattern*, one of the four invocation patterns in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly currying.

Comment: Yeah I thought that's what you were trying to get at originally, that's why I noted you're not saving the parameters that were passed in. I don't know that there is a specific name but I'll update my answer if I do find one.

Comment: Updated answer based on Crockford's book.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any generally used term for this.

The Javascript [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) wraps a function call like that, and there is no special term used.

The Prototype [`bind` method](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/bind/) does the same, and there is no term for it there either.

The jQuery [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) does the same, and there is no term for it there either.

The term "wrapping" is used in the explanations, but that is of course a lot wider term.

Comment: Pretty similar here, but I think the real question is what to call a function that morphs the input type of the arguments, which is something none of these wrapper functions do.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like you're asking "What should I call this function for readability sake?" verus "What type of/classification of function is this?", I'll throw in my two cents:

```
remixInputMethod()
```

Really, it's just a matter of rewiring the way a user of your function interacts with your program. I imagine something like this would be useful in a program where you want to interact with it by passing in input differently from the way you want your users to interact with it.

```
this.sum = function(a,b){ return a+b; };
remixInputMethod = function(fn){
    return function(arr){
        return fn.apply(fn,arr);
    };
};
var _sum = remixInputMethod(this.sum);

// Throughout your program, do some more advanced, funky stuff
var sums = (function buildListOfSums(num){
    var arr = [], output = 0;
    while(num--){
        arr.push(num);
    }

    while(arr.length > 2){
        output += _sum([arr[arr.length - 1], arr[arr.length - 2]]);
        arr.pop(arr[arr.length - 1]);
        arr.pop(arr[arr.length - 2]);
    }
    return output;
}(20));
console.log(sums);

// But for the user, lets say, who downloaded your API on Github and is using it to
// build their first webpage for their uncle
// who thinks they are smarter than bill gates
sum(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). If you're not familiar, variadic functions take a list of arguments and allows the programmer to interact with them as an array.

Since Javascript doesn't have support for variadic functions, `fn.apply(context, args)` is the way to implement it. I don't think the actual implementation is important though.

Variadic functions appear in a few different languages, my favorites include:

- C- var_args
- D
- Go

The D website has a pretty good introduction: http://dlang.org/function.html (search for variadic)

**Edit:**

Your example does the exact opposite of a variadic function. Instead of taking n number of arguments and interacting with them as an array, it's taking an array of arguments and interacting with them as separate arguments.

I still argue that this is effectively the same thing as a variadic function, since it takes a variable number of arguments, but it's just changing the way you interact with those arguments.

There's possibly a better term, but maybe we could call it an `inverse variadic function`?

Comment: I think .apply() is variadic, but this function is a user of variadic functions. Not sure if this is quite the same thing

Comment: It isn't quite. I've made a couple edits to explain why I think so. Basically, this is the only way to implement a variadic function without using apply in client code, but the effect is the same.

Comment: In terms of JavaScript, every function is built from the Object constructor which has an arguments property which is basically a variable list of arguments passed to the constructor. Every function in JavaScript has variable arity, no?

Comment: Well, there *is* [Function.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), so you can get the expected arity of the function, but this doesn't effect what appears in the `arguments` object. In Javascript, the notion of arity is fuzzy...

Comment: This isn't really making a variadic function because it doesn't change the expected arity of the underlying function `fn` that is being wrapped here.

Comment: @DaoWen - It's pretty close though. With a variadic function, you generally interact with it as an array, but it's passed as a parameter list. This is doing exactly the opposite, but I would guess it's the same idea (array => expanded parameter list).

Comment: @DaoWen - Updated my answer. I still think a variadic function is a good metaphor for what's going on though.

Comment: @tjameson - I think you misunderstood my point. This function doesn't actually give you an expanded parameter list because the underlying function (i.e. `fn` in the provided snippet) is still expecting the same number of arguments as it was before. On another note, _all_ javascript functions are variable-arity—you can pass in as many (or as few) parameters as you want and it won't complain about the invocation (although having undefined variables might cause other problems).

Comment: @DaoWen - True, you make a good point. I'm a little fuzzy on the technical definition of `variadic function`, so I'm not sure if it would apply here.